# How was "Word of Knowledge" Understood?

Tags: greek, 1-corinthians, historical-interpretation, pneumatology, spiritual-gifts

How would Paul's original audience have understood the phrase "word of knowledge" in 1 Corinthians?

> **NASB, 1 Corinthians 12:8** - For to one is given the ***word of wisdom*** through the Spirit, and to another the ***word of knowledge*** according to the same Spirit;

Is Paul's usage perhaps linked with instances in the Hebrew Text such as the below passages?

> **NASB, Proverbs 14:7** - Leave the presence of a fool, Or you will not discern ***words of knowledge***.
>
> **NASB, Proverbs 23:12** - Apply your heart to discipline And your ears to **words of knowledge**.

Comment: I'm not sure what the justification is for linking the Proverbs texts with 1 Cor 12:8. The Hebrew is either אמרי דעת as in Prov 19:27 and 23:12, or it's שפתי דעת as in Prov 14:7 and 29:15. It is never translated "word of knowledge" (as in λόγος γνώσεως = 1 Cor 12:8) by the Septuagint. The NT text is singular "word" (not plural) and the lexemes used are different. This looks to me like an inappropriate link, made via translation, and not viable in the original languages.

Comment: Please clarify to focus on a specific text and narrow it (asking how it was historically understood is too broad, asking what it meant in its original context in a specific passage is what this site is about).

Comment: @Dan - As you suggested, I copied the verse reference into the question.  Hopefully it is more clear that I am asking about 1 Corinthians 12:8.

Comment: @elikakohen I edited to focus it on the specific text and not on the broader idea of finding *any* historical usages of the phrase (I restricted it solely to this text). If the current version is fine I will reopen. It would be better to remove the Proverbs references altogether.

Comment: You may benefit from reading: [Why can't I ask my big question?](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/955/)

Comment: FYI as soon as @elikakohen indicates in a comment that the current edit is fine I will reopen.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for confirming @elikakohen - I look forward to seeing good answers to this question. I'm a former Pentecostal so the question is interesting to me personally as well. Thanks

Comment: @elikakohen This is a Good Question, and one worthy of a Good Answer. I would have to agree w/David that the links to Proverbs are tenuous at best; a better case could be made *if* one could parallel "a Word of Knowledge" from OT sources and compare it with a NT "Word of Knowledge". This would avoid the "lexeme" issue and focus on the activity itself.

Answer (score 2):

It was written a few centuries later, but one Greek commentary explains the difference between the word of wisdom [σοφία] and the word of knowledge [γνῶσις]:

> But what is “the word of wisdom?” That which Paul had, which John had,
>   the son of thunder.
>
> And what is “the word of knowledge?” That which most of the faithful
>   had, possessing indeed knowledge, but not thereupon able to teach nor
>   easily to convey to another what they knew.
>
> - John Chrysostom, [*Homily XXIX on the First Epistle to the
>   Corinthians*](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/chrysostom/1_corinthians/12.htm)

I believe that one can safely treat "word of knowledge" and "word of wisdom" as simply a way of saying "knowledge" and "wisdom", with "word of" simply referring to what one speaks.  "Knowledge" relates to knowledge of facts, whereas "wisdom" implies a deeper perception of things.

It is an interesting teaching, as it suggests that knowledge alone does not equip one to preach.

Answer (score -1):

But does a clear distinction really exist between  λόγῳ (logos) and γνώσει (gnosis) in 2 Cor 11:6 ? Yes.  In the New Testament, the rhema is a set of logos, then we can argue that the logos of the gnosis is a spiritual.